# Updating a list in Python: Why is the scope of my for-loop within a function apparently global?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, scope, global

I'm an absolute Python-Newbe and I have some trouble with following function. I hope you can help me. Thank you very much for your help in advance!

I have created a list of zip-files in a directory via a list-comprehension:

`zips_in_folder = [file for file in os.listdir(my_path) if file.endswith('.zip')]`

I then wanted to define a function that replaces a certain character at a certain index in every element fo the list with "-":

```
print(zips_in_folder)
def replacer_zip_names(r_index, replacer, zips_in_folder=zips_in_folder):
    for index, element in enumerate(zips_in_folder): 
        x = list(element)
        x[r_index] = replacer
        zips_in_folder[index]=''.join(x)
replacer_zip_names(5,"-")

print(zips_in_folder)
```

Output:

```
['12345#6', '22345#6']
['12345-6', '22345-6']
```

**The function worked, but what I cannot wrap my head around: Why will my function update the actual list "zips_in_folder". I thought the "zips_in_folder"-list within the function would only be a "shadow" of the actual list outside the function. Is the scope of the for-loop global instead of local in this case?**

In other functions I wrote the scope of the variables was always local...

I was searching for an answer for hours now, I hope my question isn't too obvious!
Thanks again!

Best
Felix

Comment: The local variable in your function is referring to exactly the same list as the global variable.  Local vs. global is a property of *variables*, not of objects.

Comment: Hey jasonharper! Thanks for your quick response! I'm just starting to learn programming. Sorry if the question is annoying: aren't variables references to objects and any variable can reference any object. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rather intermediate topic. In one line: Python is pass-by-object-reference.

### **What this means**

`zips_in_folder` is an object. An object has a reference (think of it like an address) that points to its location in memory. To access an object, you need to use its reference.
Now, here's the key part:

**For *objects* Python passes their reference as value**

This means that a copy of the *reference* of the object is created but again, the new reference is pointing to the same location in the memory.

As a consequence, if you use the reference's copy to access the object, then the original object will be modified.

In your function, `zips_in_folder` is a variable storing a new copy of the reference.
The following line is using the new copy to access the original object:

> zips_in_folder[index]=''.join(x)

However, if you decide to reassign the *variable* that is storing the reference, nothing will be done to the object, *or its original reference*, because you just reassigned the variable storing the copy of the reference, you did not modify the original object. Meaning that:

```py
def reassign(a):
  a = []

a = [1,0]
reassign(a)
print(a)  # output: [1,0]
```

Comment: Hello Karim H! That helped a lot, thank you. That explains why
```
def new_func(zips_in_folder=zips_in_folder):
  list_of_zips = zip(zips_in_folder,zip_in_folder)
```
creates an zip-object within the scope of the function, right?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to think about it is that lists are mutable, this means that the following will be true:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a           # a, b are referring to the same object
a[1] = 20       # b now is [1, 20, 3]
```

That is because lists are objects in python, not primitive variables, so the function changes the "original" list i.e. it doesn't make a local copy of it.

The same is true for any class, user-defined or otherwise: a function manipulating an object will not make a copy of the object, it will change the "original" object passed to it.

If you have knowledge of c++ or any other low-level programming language, it's the same as pass-by-reference.